# How to fix "This PC can't run Windows 10"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, bug

When trying to update Windows 10 Home I get an issue that asks me to click Fix to solve it, then I get the following error:

[image]

After closing the failed Fix window it shows:

[image]

Comment: Did you click "see compatibility details"?

Comment: @Moab ofc. that is what the pop-up is about.

Comment: Try a clean Install, there may be a driver causing this.